# Reference CDATA is URL on another website in XML parsed into PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, cdata

I have an XML exported from another website that contains `CDATA` but this `CDATA` when reference back to the website is actually a URL link.  I can parse this `CData` into `PHP` but it would be shown as text.  Is there a way I can link this `CData` back to the website where the URL is? Or I need the URL to be in the `CData` to be parse instead?

---From other website---e.g www.otherwebsite.com

e.g Node from XML

```
<SongTitle><![CDATA[This is a song link at www.otherwebsite.com]]></SongTitle>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try preg_match_all when you have loaded the file into a string..

```
$string=  '<![CDATA[This is a song link at www.otherwebsite.com]]>'; // string of data or your xml file...

preg_match_all('/<!\[(CDATA)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\]>/',$string,$out);

$current_link = $out[2][0]; // print_r($_out); to see what is in this new array...
$current_link = str_replace("This is a song link at ","",$current_link); // now remove clutter
echo $current_link;
```

if you want to handle multiple occurances of CData....

```
$var =  ' sdf sdf sdf<![CDATA[This is a song link at www.awesome.com]]> sdf sdf sd<![CDATA[This is a song link at www.google.com]]><![CDATA[This is a song link at www.amazon.com]]>';

preg_match_all('/<!\[(CDATA)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\]>/',$var,$out);
$array_of_links = $out[2];

foreach($array_of_links as $link){
    $current_link = str_replace("This is a song link at ","",$link);
    echo $current_link;
    echo "<br />";
}
```